# Debugging information for regsvr32.exe not found?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, com

So, I've got a Visual Studio 2013 solution with two Visual C++ projects - one of them is a ComServer, which generates a .dll file, and the other is the ComClient, which relies on the ComServer.dll.

Now, when I try to register the ComServer.dll file by invoking regsvr32.exe (both from c:\Windows\System32 and c:\Windows\SysWOW64), a dialog box pops up with the following error:

"Debugging information for regsvr32.exe not found. Cannot find or open the pdb file."

The project property for ComServer.dll is as follows:

ComServer property pages ->Configuration properties ->Debugging: Command:"C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe"
Command Arguments: $(TargetPath).

Is there a fix, or any possible workaround to this issue ? (I'm new to the whole COM / Windows programming scene).

The ComServer.dll contains the following functions:

DllRegisterServer
DllUnregisterServer
DllGetClassObject

Comment: You sound very confused.  That's a message you'd get from a debugger.   It doesn't "pop".  Doesn't make sense to run Regsvr32.exe with a debugger unless you are trying to debug the registration code.  In which case this notification in the Output window is entirely normal.  Proper way to debug a COM server is by debugging the client program.

Comment: Here's how you debug `DllRegisterServer()`: insert `Sleep()` and recompile, then run `regsvr32` from command line, then attach your debugger to `regsvr32.exe` process.